# JPOS purchase request gets duplicated

Tags: jpos

I am sending only one purchase request using JPOS, however I am getting duplicate requests in the logs.

```xml
<log realm="simulator_10000.server.session/127.0.0.1:50948" at="2023-05-01T09:09:25.736368">
   <session-start/>
 </log>
 <log realm="simulator_10000.server.session/127.0.0.1:50960" at="2023-05-01T09:09:25.743136">
   <session-start/>
 </log>
 <log realm="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" at="2023-05-01T09:09:26.002006" lifespan="431ms">
   <abort>
     txnmgr-2:idle:12
     <context>
       CC_TR_REQUEST(P): 
        <isomsg direction="outgoing">
          <!-- net.shamirix.utils.CustomPacker1993 -->
          <field id="0" value="1200"/>
          <field id="2" value="2223600089700011"/>
          <field id="3" value="000000"/>
          <field id="4" value="000000000014"/>
          <field id="7" value="0501090925"/>
         …
          <field id="64" value="10011001"/>
          <field id="128" value="A8CDDA88FFFFFFFF" type="binary"/>
        </isomsg>
       
       CC_ISO_SOURCE: org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel@1089f917
       RESPONSE: 
        <isomsg direction="incoming">
          <!-- net.shamirix.utils.CustomPacker1993 -->
          <field id="0" value="1210"/>
          <field id="2" value="2223600089700011"/>
          <field id="3" value="000000"/>
          <field id="4" value="000000000014"/>
          <field id="7" value="0501090925"/>
          …
          <field id="64" value="3130303131303031" type="binary"/>
          <field id="128" value="A8CDDA88FFFFFFFF" type="binary"/>
[![jpos logs][1]][1]
        </isomsg>

       

       DESTINATION: jPOS-AUTORESPONDER
       REQUEST(P): 
        <isomsg direction="outgoing">
          <!-- net.shamirix.utils.CustomPacker1993 -->
          <field id="0" value="1200"/>
          <field id="2" value="2223600089700011"/>
          <field id="3" value="000000"/>
          <field id="4" value="000000000014"/>
          <field id="7" value="0501090925"/>
          …
          <field id="64" value="10011001"/>
          <field id="128" value="A8CDDA88FFFFFFFF" type="binary"/>
        </isomsg>
       
       PAYMENT_PROCESSOR_RESPONSE: 
        <isomsg direction="incoming">
          <!-- net.shamirix.utils.CustomPacker1993 -->
          <field id="0" value="1210"/>
          <field id="2" value="2223600089700011"/>
          <field id="3" value="000000"/>
          <field id="4" value="000000000014"/>
          <field id="7" value="0501090925"/>
          …
          <field id="64" value="3130303131303031" type="binary"/>
          <field id="128" value="A8CDDA88FFFFFFFF" type="binary"/>
        </isomsg>
       
       Error: unconnected ISOChannel
     </context>
                 in-transit=3/4, head=14, tail=10, paused=0, outstanding=0, active-sessions=4/250, tps=0, peak=2, avg=0.01, elapsed=431ms
     
   </abort>
 </log>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two different entries, `REQUEST` and `CC_TR_REQUEST` placed there probably by two different participants. I noticed you are setting the persist flag to true (that's the `(P)` indicator you see in the logs) by setting the boolean third parameter in `ctx.put` and while that can be totally OK, I wonder if that's what you really want. You need to take into account that this could persist sensitive data.